# javascript - Parse string to JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

Sorry, a little new to this. But I am trying to achieve the following. I have this (the `fullName` string is returned from a webapp UI using selenium webdriverIO):

```
const fullName = "Mr Jason Biggs";
```

And need it to look like this:

```
title: 'Mr',
name: 'Jason',
surname: 'Biggs',
```

I tried splitting the name, but not sure how to add a k to the v

```
const splitName = fullName.split(" ");
// But returns as [ 'Mr', 'Jason', 'Biggs' ]
```

Comment: `arr = ['Mr', 'Jason', 'Biggs']`. `beautiful_name = { title: arr[0], name: arr[1], surname: arr[2] }`

Comment: add a k to the v? What do you mean? Anyway you can do `{ title:splitName[0], name:splitName[1], surname:splitName[3] }`

Comment: JSON is a text format; you appear to want a data structure in the JavaScript execution environment, not a JSON-serialized string that represents an object. (In other words: you want to create an "object" not a "JSON object".) JSON serialization doesn't appear to have anything to do with your goal here. You you really *do* want a JSON string, you need to take the existing answers and pass their result into `JSON.stringify`

Answer (score 2):

Just create a new object and assign those splitted parts to its keys:

```js
const fullName = "Mr Jason Biggs";

const splitName = fullName.split(" "),
      object = { 
          title: splitName[0],
          name: splitName[1],
          surname: splitName[2]
      };
      
console.log(object);
```

If you have a lot of strings that needs this work to be done, then just wrap the code in a function `getObject` that takes a string and returns the object:

```js
function getObject(str) {
    const splitName = str.split(" ");
    return {
        title: splitName[0],
        name: splitName[1],
        surname: splitName[2]
    };
}


const arrayOfStrings = ["Mr Jason Biggs", "Dr Stephen Strange", "Ms Lilly Depp"];

console.log(arrayOfStrings.map(getObject));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get fancy and use newer syntax, you can use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) as well:

```js
    const fullName = "Mr Jason Biggs";

    // Split and assign to named vars
    const [title, name, surname] = fullName.split(' ');
    // Create object from the new vars with the property value shorthand
    const obj = {
      title,
      name,
      surname
    };
    
    console.log(obj);
```

Comment: I just wanted to post the same answer (using object literal property name shorthand). I'm glad someone had the same idea. Take my upvote.